# Would the powerset of $\mathbb{Z}$ also not denumerable?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

Would the powerset of $\mathbb{Z}$ also be not denumerable?, Since Cantor's theorem says that the $\mathbb{N}$ is denumberable but the powerset of $\mathbb{N}$ is not denumberable because there does not exist a surjective function from $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow$ $P( \mathbb{N} )$

I feel like this should be true for $\mathbb{Z}$ as well am I wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Since $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb N$ have the same cardinality, so do $P(\mathbb Z)$ and $P(\mathbb N)$.

Comment: I see, I was wondering the same thing. So would a proof by contradiction be a reasonable proof to show that there does not exist a bijectve function from  $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow$ $P( \mathbb{N} )$

Comment: That's not the question you asked. You asked if $P(\mathbb Z)$ is countable, which asks if there is an onto map $\mathbb N\to P(\mathbb Z)$.

Comment: And yes, contradiction is the right way. There is an onto map $P(\mathbb Z)\to P(\mathbb N)$, so if there is an onto map $\mathbb N\to P(\mathbb Z)$ the composition would yield an onto map $\mathbb N\to P(\mathbb N)$.